# How do I set multiple consequences of "if /p" command?

Tags: batch-file

The issue i've been having is trying to have multiple things print out after the player responds with a certain command. For example:

```
set /p where=
if %where% equ EAT set /a "food = %food% - 1" 
if %where% equ EAT set /a "hp = %hp% + 3" 
set /p where=
pause
```

What I want to happen is the players' food to be reduced by one, while his hp is increased by 3. I can do these simply enough on their own, but I need them to happen as a consequence of the player typing "EAT" in response. I've tried putting multiple `%where%` clauses with the same value, but they don't respond.

Removing the whitespace didn't work. I think i'd need a way to tell the console to activate my other lines of code.

---

Fixed! Issue was partly /a having issues, partly the variables not updating on screen.

Comment: Remove the whitespace before the **`=`**.

Comment: `if %where% equ EAT set /a "food=food-1, hp=hp+3"` or `... set /a "food-=1, hp+=3"`